# Get the index of the row whose dropdown is selected --JS

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have multiple rows dynamically created that consists of dropdowns.

I'm trying to get the rowIndex of the dropdown I selected. For example in the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/gfhwd0fc/
Im looking for the index of the ROW selected. like there are 3 rows in the above ex, which ever option I select from drodown, it looks for the row in which the dropdown is located.

I'm looking for the row index and not OPTION index selected from the dropdown.

my code is in EXTJS;

```
 {
                    columnWidth: .5,
                    height : 30,
                    help: 'operator',
                    xtype : 'combo',
                    name: 'operator',
                    width: 150,
                    ref: "../operator",
                    emptyText: $L("Select Operator..."),

                    store: new Ext.data.ArrayStore({
                         fields: ['key', 'title'],
                         data: values
                     }),
                     listeners: {

                         'select': function(rec) {
                             //do some stuff here to get the index

                         },
                         scope: this
                     },
                    editable: false

                },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the selected property on the children (options) of the select elements. Something like this:

https://jsfiddle.net/ibowankenobi/gfhwd0fc/2/

```
var result = document.getElementById("result");
function handler(e){
    var children = Array.prototype.slice.call(this.children);
    e.currentTarget.__row = result.textContent = children.indexOf(
    children.filter(function(d,i){return d.selected})[0]
  ); 
}
Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll("select")).forEach(function(d,i){
    d.addEventListener("change",handler,false);
});
```

you will have .__row property on the select tags on change.

## PS:

Apparantely there is also the selectedIndex on the parent select element, which didn't cross my mind. Anyway I'll leave this crud solution as a custom dom implementation xD.

Comment: So i think your solution does not give the index of the "ROW" selected, it gives the index of the "OPTION" selected. I was looking for the index of the ROW selected. like there are 3 rows in the above ex, which ever option I select from drodown, it look for the row in which the dropdown is located..Thanks

Comment: Then I misunderstood your question.